# MS-SQL JOIN with multiple SUBSTRING and LIKE

Tags: sql

I have a MS SQL 2005/2008 database and trying to compare two tables of data using substrings with % wildcard to try and find data within one character of a column in other table.

Example is:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.Marker = 1
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.ForeignKey = table2.ID
AND tabl1.CharacterColumn LIKE SUBSTRING(table2.CharacterColumn , 1, 5) + '%' + SUBSTRING(table2.CharacterColumn , 7, 8) 

UPDATE table1
SET table1.Marker = 1
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.ForeignKey = table2.ID
AND tabl1.CharacterColumn LIKE SUBSTRING(table2.CharacterColumn , 1, 6) + '%' + SUBSTRING(table2.CharacterColumn , 8, 8)
```

At present it takes a while to run this routine as the column can contain up to 10 characters and the dataset is on a table1 of 300 million rows (however a dataset of maybe 300k) and table2 of 2 million rows (a dataset of 100k).

My question is is the JOIN statement the best way to do one character out searching on a column?

i can't give exact examples as the data is protected, however this should help:

Table2 -

```
ID | FK | Name  
1 | 100 | Phillips  
2 | 100 | Bloggs  
3 | 100 | Jones
```

Table1 -

```
ID | Table2FK | Name 
1 | 100 | Philpips 
2 | 100 | Bloggs 
3 | 100 | Jones
```

As you see table2 record 1 is within one character of table1 record 1 and I want to identify that. Also the one character out can be at any point in the string

Comment: Could you post some same data for the 2 tables? Might make your question clearer

Comment: Sure, i can't give exact examples as the data is protected, however this should help:
Table2 - 
ID | FK       | Name
1  | 100      | Phillips
2  | 100      | Bloggs
3  | 100      | Jones

Table1 - 
ID | Table2FK | Name
1  | 100      | Philpips
2  | 100      | Bloggs
3  | 100      | Jones

As you see table2 record 1 is within one character of table1 record 1 and I want to identify that. Also the one character out can be at any point in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you wrap column in SQL function, SQL Server is no longer able to use indexes. If you have large tables like you have described SQL Server will need to do many CPU intensive operations like Index Scan. Your have 2 alternatives

1. Create indexed view with a columns of that sub-string. It will take longer to build it first time but after that you will be able to easily join.
2. Second alternative is to modify your tables to break apart character column into two separate column and that create index on those two columns.

String operations are very costly and it is best to be able to break strings apart instead into separate columns instead of doing it real time.

Indexed Views Documentation http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the issue I'm having is that the string is variable in length in both table1 and table2, also table1 has 300k of data to join into a potential 9 million rows in table2 (as I can't use the string as part of the join which would reduce the dataset dramatically)

Comment: In that case you would need to reconsider your structure of how it is stored. What this sounds like is that someone is making unreasonable request without understanding implications and asking you to make it fast.